# Highcharts(highstock) line chart Tooltip shows previous date

Tags: highcharts

[image]I am using Highcharts(Highstock) v4.2.5. 
I have a linechart with irregular date values on xAxis, and float values on yaxis. My problem is that on hover, the tooltip shows a previous date for the values of next date.

E.g hovering on 06-Apr-2014 data point, shows tooltip with wrong date as 05-Apr-2016 but correct data values.

Why is the date in tooltip showing a previous day?

My JS code is below

```
{
"xAxis": {
    "type": "linear"
},

"tooltip": {
    "borderColor" : "red"
},

"credits" :  {
    "enabled" : true
},
"navigator" :{
    "enabled": true
},
"scrollbar" :{
    "enabled": true
},

"rangeSelector" :  {
    "allButtonsEnabled" : true
}, 

"legend" :  {
    "enabled" : true
},
"title" : {
    "text" : ""
},

"series" : []
}
```

JSON returned from server is

```
{
"multilinedata": [{
    "name": "BHIBOR O/N Rate",
    "data": [
        [1377637200000, 2.25], -> this is 28-AUG-2013
        [1396731600000, 1] -> this is 06-APR-2014
    ]
}]

}
```

Comment: Your time is in UTC, if not please disable that by param [useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC)

Comment: actually there is no time involved in here, but i saw the example on highcharts demo, with date converted to UTC, so i was also converting to UTC. Should'nt it work with UTC ? Also, how do i disbale UTC only for a particular chart ?

Comment: Can you replicate this demo as live example on the jsfiddle.net or send reference to Highcharts exampel which introduce the issue ?

Comment: There is always time involved, whether or not you specify it. Time defaults to midnight so if the UTC setting is causing your hour to shift to an earlier time, it will push the date back a day.

Comment: Apologies to all. The problem was the UTC time, which was pushing the date back.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, by passing the time 24:00:00 to my date conversion method. By passing the time, the date was not pushing back.

Thanks to @Sebastian Bochan and @jlbriggs